# New to Linux- using 32bit Ubuntu-Mate 18

Tags: sound, soundcard

New to Linux. using Ubuntu-Mate 18.04 due to PC limits (WinXP unit).
Cant hear any audio! Not on Rhythmbox or VLC media player.
Sound settings say "Dummy Output stereo".
What script can I use to remedy my absent audio output issue?

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome! Unfortunately, there are no longer any currently supported versions of Ubuntu that work for 32-bit only x86 hardware.  However there are some other distributions that still support this architecture. Ubuntu is based on Debian which still supports 32-bit hardware. Perhaps you should give it a try: https://www.debian.org/distrib/

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu-MATE 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-18-04-lts-reaches-end-of-life/23966/7 or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* only had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with MATE

Comment: @Nmath  Am I mistaken that 18.04 is still supported?  Know that Mate desktop would be out of support.

Comment: @crip659 the only versions of 18.04 that had 32-bit support were flavors, which had 3 years of support that ended in 2021.

Comment: Is your machine actually 32-bit??  Almost most OEMs of computers sold 32-bit windows on lower-end devices as Microsoft sold 32-bit windows for $5 less than the 64-bit version, so most low-end machines had 32-bit windows on 64-bit *amd64* hardware as buyers understood $5 far more than the 32 vs 64 bits debate. I'd check you have 32-bit as most desktops from 2003 onwards is *amd64*, and laptops from 2005 & later are *amd64* (except for some intel atom n270 type netbooks sold until 2007).  I'd check your machine capabilities.

Comment: Also please note Ubuntu products using the *year* format are different systems to those using the *year.month* format.  Ubuntu MATE is a desktop release; so is not available for Ubuntu Core 18 or any 18 system, it was released only for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (ie. a *deb* based system, not *snap* based 18)

Comment: My understanding is that flavors of Ubuntu LTS releases are supported by AU for five years just like the main Ubuntu.

Comment: FYI: @Nmath, 18.04 was fully supported for 18.04 & not just via *flavors*, eg. look at http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/389/builds and you'll note numerous i386 ISOs were produced with 5 years supported life (it was just missing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop, where media had been stopped in prior releases; but *release-upgrades* for users who wanted it were still supported; or other ISO media could be used & `ubuntu-desktop` added if really needed).  Yes *flavors* are now all EOL..  *i386* media continued to be produced into the *disco* or 19.04 cycle with fewer install options..

Comment: @crip659, really old device. was gift in 2k2/2k3. old Gateway tower. when I try to install any 64-bit iso, get "...kernel needs x86-64...only sees i686..." message & install stops. So no fix other than get new device?

Comment: Think Debian and the small/tiny Linuxs still support 32bit, but it will get harder to find browsers and other programs to support it.  Chrome drop support years ago.  Have an old P4 that have basically retired.

Comment: anyone have opinion on Emmabuntus? search found OS said to be compatible w/old devices. Any issues? Any better alternatives?

Comment: Only Ubuntu and [*flavors* of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here..  You didn't specify which kernel stack you were using with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS; I've had better luck with the older GA kernel stack on really old devices (ie. ~2002-2004) over the newer HWE kernel stack.  The significance being what most people call *drivers* are actually kernel modules; thus related to the kernel.  Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel choices; the installation media used dictates the default (you didn't specify which 18.04 media you used; there are 12 ISOs of Ubuntu MATE 18.04)